# Is it possible to extract specific CSS property from one css file to another?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm wondering, is there any way that I can exclude or extract some specific CSS properties from one CSS file to another?

For example, I have a style.css file, from which I only want to extract all the background and color properties to another CSS file. Is it possible in any way?

TIA

Comment: Yes it is, you can make them variables and include them in your final css file but you need to use a js task manager and sass are you using one?

Comment: Variables could definitely work, but why not just use classes and add them as needed?

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: I mean an actual example in code :)

Comment: Well, I think I am not clear to you. I am currently using gulp and sass. My question was to extract some specific css property from a css file. For colors, I am using variables as well as classes. But extending those classes generating a chunk of styles in the main file. So what I want is, to generate css for those color classes (like I said specific css properties) in a separate file. Is it possible? Yeah, I can just copy, paste. But I want to know is there any automated way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution at last!
This kinda works but needs more tweaks and improvements.

```js
let at_data='';
 var css=[];
 var openFile=function(event) {
 var input=event.target;
 var reader=new FileReader();
 reader.onload=function() {
  var text=reader.result;
  var node=document.getElementById('output');
  //node.innerText=text;
  at_data=reader.result.substring();
  at_data.split('}').map(item=> {
   var item2=item.trim();
   var item3=(item2 +"}");
   css.push(item3)
  }
  );
  css.pop();
  //console.log(css);
 }
 ;
 reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}
;
//console.log(css)
 function getCss (property,
value) {
 const filter=css.filter(function(item, index) {
  const filter2=item.split('{')[1].split(';').filter(function(item2, index) {
   if(item2.trim().startsWith(property)) {
    if(item2.split(':')[1] !==undefined) {
     if(item2.split(':')[1].trim().startsWith(value)) {
      return item2
     }
    }
   }
  }
  );
  return item.includes(filter2[0]);
 }
 );
 var data1='';
 filter.map(data=> {
  data1 +='<p>'+data+'</p>'
 }
 );
 data1 +='';
 document.getElementById('article').innerHTML=data1;
}
var btn=document.getElementById('getStyle');
 btn.addEventListener('click',
function () {
 let pro=document.getElementById('property').value, value=document.getElementById('value').value;
 getCss(pro, value)
}
);
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output'></div>

<input type="text" id='property' value='' placeholder="property">
<input type="text" id='value' value='' placeholder="value">
<button id="getStyle">Click</button>

<article id="article"></article>
```